# Why can linear operators on $\mathbb{C}^n$ be identified with complex $n\times n$ matrices?

Tags: operator-theory

Why can $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ (the linear operators on $\mathbb{C}$) be identified with $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (the complex $n\times n$ matrices)?
I just came across this claim in Engel & Nagel's [*One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97696).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are both complex vector spaces. Let $\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_n$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

We define $\Phi:\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to be the map taking each $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ to the $n\times n$ matrix whose $j^{\text{th}}$ column is $T(\mathbf{e}_j)$. Using the fact that each $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is uniquely determined by its action on the standard basis vectors, one can check that $\Phi$ is a linear isomorphism (and so its inverse is automatically a linear isomorphism also).

In other words, $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ and $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are identical not only as sets, but as *complex vector spaces* since the linear isomorphism preserves the linear structure. This is why we can think of them as one and the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my confusion came from the phrase "linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^n$" since an operator I understand should act on function spaces but in this case it acts on the complex space

Comment: @eraldcoil The term 'linear operator' usually refers simply to a linear map from a vector space to itself. The fancy term for this is an *endomorphism* of the vector space.